# sublime text 2 command create link but the command is empty

Tags: macos, bash, sublime-text-2

I want to create the link about sublime text2 which is placed in applications.

If I paste the `/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl` in bash, the sublime text 2 will open.

And I use the

`sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl`

and I check that my path has add the `/usr/local/bin` by `echo $PATH` which results in `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:`

and I cd to the `/usr/local/bin` and found there is a subl script but I use vim to open it, the file is all blank.

And I restart the terminal and type `subl` but results `-bash: subl: command not found`.

How do I fixed it?

Comment: if you use sublime text 3, the issue is fixed, at least on linux (don't have osx so dont how osx woorks) they started to offer .deb installable packages and not just zip files with an executable file. I can do `subl abc.txt` from terminal, by default, so you might want to try it

Comment: @Fischer - OSX doesn't support `.deb` packages, so unfortunately that solution is irrelevant here. Creating the `subl` link isn't too hard, you just need to make sure the path is correct - see my [answer](http://superuser.com/a/642334/137557) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use Sublime Text 3 yet, which has a lot of differences from Sublime Text 2, and is still in beta, here's how to fix your problem. Just run each of these commands (in order) from Terminal and you should be all set:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/subl
```

This will remove whatever `subl` links are in `/usr/local/bin`. Then:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin
```

This recreates the link to the proper location. Make sure you run the command exactly as I typed it, or it won't work. I'll explain why in a moment. Finally, restart Terminal and enter:

```
subl
```

to make sure the process worked.

---

The reason your

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

command didn't work was because you included the `Applications/...` path in quotes `"` **and also** escaped the spaces using a backslash `\`. You should do one or the other, but not both. My command above just uses `\` to escape the spaces. When you use quotes, each character in the string is included literally, including the `\` characters. This is why the file was blank when you opened it in `vim` - it was pointing to a path that didn't exist.

By the way, while you can open `/usr/local/bin/subl` in `vim`, I wouldn't recommend it because it's a binary executable file, so you'll just get garbage on your screen.

Good luck!