# Having trouble creating symlink between the terminal in Mac OS X and Sublime Text 2 so it can be launched from the command line

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, symbolic-link, sublime-text-2

I’m using Mac OS X Yosemite and I want to be able to open Sublime Text 2 from the terminal with a command like this:

```
sublime .
```

I’ve typed this into terminal [as shown on the Sublime Text 2 website:](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html)

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/sublime
```

And also this variant:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

In the terminal, if I type in:

```
echo $PATH
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I’ve tried editing my `.bash_profile`, right now it’s blank

After all this, I try `sublime .` and get the following error:

> -bash: sublime: command not found

I’m completely new to Mac OS X, and terminal configuration, and am really struggling to figure out why I can't get it to work so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found another [post](http://superuser.com/questions/641966/sublime-text-2-command-create-link-but-the-command-is-empty?rq=1) that solved my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running [the back-slashed/escaped version of the `ln -s` command as explained here](https://gist.github.com/artero/1236170) like so:

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

As that site explains—and I concur—the `~/bin` that the official Sublime Text site recommends just seems weird and I have never encountered a recommendation like that for local binaries before. So avoid using it.

But what is also weird in all examples is that `sudo` is not being used. That `/usr/local/bin` directory is a root system directory and is not normally writable by anyone but `root`. So with that in mind just run the above command via `sudo` like this:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

Of course you will now have to enter your root/administrator password. But once that is done the symbolic link should be in place. And to confirm it’s there just run this command from the terminal:

```
ls -la /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

The output should be a directory listing with dates/times that looks something like the following:

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel       27 Aug 21  2015 sublime -> /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I think your solution is spot on, but the problem was that we weren't removing the old symlink I had created using the official Sublime Text site recommendation. At least, that's how I understand it.

Comment: Nearly 3 years later this answer sorted the issue for me as well. The quoted version of `ln -s` as provided by the instructions weren't working for me, switching to the backslashed/escaped version as well as using sudo solved everything perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

This should be a very simple thing, with the built in `open` command --

```
open -a "Sublime Text 2"
```

You can also create a `sublime` command alias for that.

```
alias sublime='open -a "Sublime Text 2"'
```

Answer (score -1):

I've done this so many times that I recommend:

1. adding an alias to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` (`alias sublime="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"`)
2. moving that RC file to iCloud Drive, and symlinking that file back into your root `~`

---

`ln -s "/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/.zshrc" ~/.zshrc`

---

if you use zsh, you can `export icloud="/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs"`

Comment: “moving that RC file to iCloud Drive, and symlinking that file back into your root `~`” Why? Why add “the cloud” to a simply alias/symlink?